# DAO design to update an entity in DB

Tags: java, design-patterns, dao

Lets say a client updates an entity ( Ex: student entity ).
So we get the student Id and other modified fields (not all fields) from the client.

I read that we should pass the particular entity object to DAO in order to update.
But then , how will I get to form that entity object.Because I don't have all fields data to create a proper entity object.

**Should I make two DB calls ?**

The first call is to construct a proper entity object and then make the update by passing this updated entity object to the DAO.

Comment: Pretty much, yes. One call to fetch the (old object), one call to update the object. If the entity is still attached in the DAO layer (i.e. the transaction is still open), it is sufficient to fetch & modify the object without persisting it. The changes will be persisted automatically when the transaction is closed (this, of course, uses a db query).

Comment: Thank you @Turing85

Answer (score 2):

The only way to avoid two DB calls is to use an update statement to update only th fields you have. E.g.

```
UPDATE Student SET someField1 = :field1, someField2 = :field2 WHERE ID = :id
```

Remember that update queries bypass optimistic locking checks.
If you use optimistic locking you should append the version to the where clause and also increment it.

```
UPDATE Student SET someField1 = :field1, version = version + 1 WHERE id = :id AND version = :version
```

After an executeUpdate you should check the affected rows:

- 1 : everything is ok
- 0 : the entity could either not be found by it's id. Maybe it was deleted in the meanwhile or the version did not match. In both cases you should raise an OptimisticLockException.
- >1 : you should raise an exception to rollback the transaction.

Comment: Depends on your use case. Usually I would recommend to load the entity and update it. Just like Turing85 said in his comment. But if you want to update a lot of entities in a batch process, it might be better to use update statements.